# How to do elimination in matlab?

Tags: matlab

How to calculate this kind of matrix :

```
A = [ 1  3 4
      4  5 7
      10 8 6]

X= [x1
    x2
    x3]

Y= A*X=0
```

we can change it into :

```
   1x1+3x2+4x3=0
   4x1+5x2+7x3=0
   10x1+8x2+6x3=0
```

How to do elimination in Matlab to get the x1, x2 and x3??

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. 
I suppose you want a way to solve a SLE. There are few way to this, the one that I personally find more straightforward is

```
 x=A\b
```

where in your case:

```
 b=zeros(3,1)
```

Note that you don't need the vector you're calling X as MATLAB will automatically consider the values in A as coefficient of different variables

Comment: I already tried it, and the result x =0;0;0. All became zero.. Do u have another solution??

Comment: It becomes 0 because zero is the solution of your system.

Comment: @cifz is right. try `b=[8;16;24]` and get `x=[1;1;1]`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you created an example for this question, but didn't really check if it would produce the desired result. For Ax = 0 to have a non-zero solution, the determinant `det(A)` must be zero. As the determinant of your `A` matrix is `40`, the only solution is `x = [0; 0; 0]`.

Now, assuming you picked a better example, such as:

```
A = [1 2 3;2 4 6;1 1 1];
```

Now, `det(A) = 0`.

Using regular `linsolve`, you will still only get `x = [0; 0; 0]` as a solution. However, there are clearly (infinitely) many other non-trivial solutions. You can achieve one such solution using [`null`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/null.html) like this:

```
x = null(A)
x =
    0.4082
   -0.8165
    0.4082

A*x
ans =
  1.0e-014 *
    0.1110
    0.2220
    0.0944
```

Which is practically zero (inaccuracies are due to floating point precision).

You can also use Singular value decomposition, [`svd`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) to get the same results:

```
[U S V] = svd(A);
x = V(:,end)
x =
    0.4082
   -0.8165
    0.4082

A*x
ans =
  1.0e-014 *
    0.1110
    0.2220
    0.0944
```